# Trigger.io Android NullPointerException in logcat when starting app

Tags: android, trigger.io, facebook-android-sdk

Building an Android / html hybrid app with Trigger.IO Forge.
Signed app with Android keystore, ran build, transferred to phone.

Launched app successfully, it opened. Tried to login with Facebook (Forge.facebook.authorize) - saw error in ABD Logcat regarding mis-matched Facebook keyhash:

```
    D/Forge   (14638): Returning: {"content":{"type":"EXPECTED_FAILURE","message":"i
    nvalid_key:Android key mismatch. Your key \"mykeywasherexxxxxxxxx\" does n
    ot match the allowed keys specified in your application settings. Check your app
    lication settings at http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/developers"},"status":"error","c
    allid":"89C92BE0-XXXX-4E13-BA20-19F330DF353E"}
```

Updated keyhash on developers.facebook.com

Now when app is launched, the initial html screen (as seen after succesfully logging in) partially renders and then the app crashes immediately. Capture from logcat:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(11373): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(11373): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
0f80300)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(11373): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity$2
.onConsoleMessage(ForgeActivity.java:179)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(Ca
llbackProxy.java:796)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:4745)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
11)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:553)
E/AndroidRuntime(11373):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

W/ActivityManager(  304):   Force finishing activity com.wewana.play/io.trigger.
forge.android.core.ForgeActivity
D/dalvikvm(  304): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1780K, 21% free 32600K/41031K, paused 106m
s, total 106ms
D/Forge   (11373): Native call "launchimage.hide" with task.params: {}
D/Forge   (11373): Returning: {"status":"success","callid":"15C77379-8B2F-4DBC-9
34D-0D1B0BB96E14"}
W/ActivityManager(  304): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41fe8630 com
.wewana.play/io.trigger.forge.android.core.ForgeActivity}
```

Comment: It appears something you're logging to the console is breaking our interception of those messages. Switching to forge.logging should fix the problem, but it would be great if you could narrow down what the problem message is to help us out!

Comment: Wrote a wrapper function and swapped all my console.log()s out, will see if the issue returns!
`MyApp.debug = function (logmessage) {
    var output = _.map(arguments, function (message) { return JSON.stringify(message) });
    output = output.join();
    // if forge enabled log to forge
    if (typeof forge !== "undefined") {
        forge.logging.debug(output);
    } else {
        // else use console.log
        MyApp.debug(output);
    }
};`

Comment: uuurgh, ugly formatting in these comments